# Store content of a C pointer into a file with Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, openssl

I have a CMS_ContentInfo pointer...

```
    CMS_ContentInfo *encryptedDataWithCMS = CMS_encrypt(certList, dataToEncrypt, cipher, NULL);
```

... and I would like to store the CMS_ContentInfo into a new .p7m file.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

EDIT: Furthermore I need to save it in objective-c (any instance of NSObject).

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but to write the contents of a structure:

```
void writePtr( CMS_ContentInfo *tehPtr ){

    FILE *tehFile;

    //opens the file you want to write in, please notice the fopen mode "wb".
    tehFile = fopen( "tehFilePath", "wb" );
    //write 1 block of sizeOf( CMS_ContentInfo ) bytes into tehFile with the contents
    //of tehPtr
    fwrite( tehPtr, sizeOf( CMS_ContentInfo ), 1, tehFile );

    fclose( tehFile );

}

CMS_ContentInfo readPtr(){

    FILE *tehFile;
    CMS_ContentInfo *tehPtr;

    //opens the file you want to read from, please notice the fopen mode "rb".
    tehFile = fopen( "tehFilePath", "rb" );
    //allocates tho pointer where the read data will be stored.
    tehPtr = (CMS_ContentInfo *) malloc( sizeOf(CMS_ContentInfo) );

    //reads 1 block of sizeOf( CMS_ContentInfo ) bytes from tehFile into tehPtr
    fread( tehPtr, sizeOf( CMS_ContentInfo ), 1, tehFile );

    fclose( tehFile );

    return tehPtr;

}
```

Comment: Partially yes but I need it in Objective-c. :) That's my problem. I have a c pointer and need to "convert" it into a NSObject (or an inherited instance of it) to save it using Apples API calls. (What I mean is to save it with objective-c syntax to prevent problems with a manually save using fopen, fwrite, etc.)

Comment: @Chris: You can use whitelionV's technique to save it into an `NSMutableData` instead of writing to a file, and then you can save that data however you want. Note however, that whitelionV's suggestion is merely a way to save the bits that make up a structure. If CMS_ContentInfo contains any pointers it won't be appropriate.

Comment: @KevinBallard How?
I've tried:
 NSMutableData *data;
        write( encryptedDataWithCMS, sizeof( encryptedDataWithCMS ), 1, data );

and...

        NSMutableData *temp = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:encryptedDataWithCMS length:sizeof(encryptedDataWithCMS)];

Comment: @Chris: Well, obviously you wouldn't use `write()` to try and put something in an `NSMutableData`. You can use the methods on `NSMutableData`, e.g. `-appendBytes:length:` in lieu of the `write()` call.